# how to create log files in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, deployment

I have developed a web application using spring boot and it works perfectly fine in my local machine.Now I want to run the application in a web server.So I am going to export it as a WAR file and deploy it.But now only I got to know about logging.So I have added the log4j jar file and should I write some code for creating the logs or will spring take care of it?I am deploying a web application for the first time and I have no idea about it.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ***How?*** Read the documentation: [Spring Boot Reference Guide - Part IX. ‘How-to’ guides - 73. Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html). Down-voting because *"This question does not show any research effort"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add log4j dependency like this:

```
<!-- log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

You should to add some code like this:

```
public Controller{
   private static Logger logger  = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);
   public void log(){
      logger.info("log4j is work");
   }

}
```

Don't forget add the lo4j config file log4j.properties.You can use the follow config convenient.

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO
log4j.appender.INFO = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.INFO.File = ${catalina.home}/logs/info.log
log4j.appender.INFO.Append = true
log4j.appender.INFO.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.INFO.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

This config will output the log into the `${catalina.home}/logs/info.log`.`${catalina.home}` means  servlet container directory.
Please learn more complex log4j config by google :)

Answer (score 2):

In `application.properties` configure this values:

```
logging.level: DEBUG
logging.level: ERROR
logging.file: ${HOME}/application.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` you can configure below value:
`logging.config=file:Path to log4j.properties`
And configure your log4j.properties file as:

```
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.File=/path/to store/logFile/logFile-debug.log
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.layout.conversionPattern=[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Do same configurations for `info` and `error` logs.